# Get Search term in custom Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento-2.0

I want to retrieve the search term in my Observer for use elsewhere but I cant seem to find out how to extract the data.

So far I have tried this (search term is `Football`):

events.xml:

```
<event name='abstract_search_result_load_before'>
        <observer
           name='Path\To\This\Search.php'
           instance='Path\To\This\Search.php'
        />
</event>
```

Search Observer:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $this->myhelper ->log('search');

    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $collection = $event->getData('collection');
    $search = $collection->getSearchCriteria();

    $this->myhelper->log('************' . var_export($search, true));
}
```

Produces:

```
main.INFO: search [] []
main.INFO: ************Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status\StockStatusCriteria::__set_state(array(
   'data' => 
  array (
    'fields' => 
    array (
      'list' => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
    'filters' => 
    array (
      'list' => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
    'orders' => 
    array (
      'list' => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
    'criteria_list' => 
    array (
      'list' => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
    'initial_condition' => true,
    'products_filter' => '7',
    'website_filter' => '1',
  ),
   'mapperInterfaceName' => 'Magento\\CatalogInventory\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Stock\\Status\\StockStatusCriteriaMapper',
)) [] []
```

Comment: Do you realize that this is a `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status\StockStatusCriteria`? Magento 2 uses SearchCriteria objects in many places, not just the catalog search. So in this case, there is no "search term".

Comment: Right got you! Do you know of a way to get the search term? It must be retrievable surely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, Magento 2 uses SearchCriteria objects in many places, not just the catalog search. So in this case, there is no "search term".

Which event you should use depends on what you actually want to do. But on a search request you should be able to retrieve the current query like this at any time:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory $queryFactory)
{
    $this->queryFactory = $queryFactory;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $searchTerm = $this->queryFactory->get()->getQueryText();
}
```

Because [the search result controller](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Controller/Result/Index.php) uses a shared instance of `Magento\Search\Model\Query` which is managed by the QueryFactory instance.

Comment: Thank you seems like it will work, however I am listening to events which triggers specific Observers any idea which event is based to hook into, im trying different ones but sometimes its firing 10+ times on an add to basket event.

Comment: Maybe `controller_action_postdispatch_catalogsearch_result_index` works for you? It's called after the search request has been processed.

Comment: The event seems to respond but its always returning null even with a search term being used. Dont really understand why trying to look through magento source to figure it out!

Comment: I tested it. Looks like you have to inject `QueryFactory` instead of `Query` and then call `$this->queryFactory->get()->getQueryText()` because the shared instance is managed by this factory, not the object manager itself. This is the clean way. But if you are using the postdispatch event, you could also use `$event->getRequest()->getParam('q')`.

Comment: @ChrisEdwards I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This helped lead me in the right direction to retrieve the search query text on the search page for tracking purposes. Thanks!

Comment: When Full page cache is enabled, Observer for controller_action_postdispatch_catalogsearch_result_index calling only one time. Any solution for this please?

Comment: @Magecode this is a complete different question, you should use the "Ask Question" button for this (but then also provide more context on what you are trying to achieve so that people can actually help you)

Comment: Please check this question I have already posted.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269631/magento-2-issue-observer-calling-only-one-time-when-get-search-term-using-observ

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Mage::helper('catalogSearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText();
```

Comment: That is for magento 1, I need it for magento2 :/