# Magento 2 Issue Observer Calling only One Time when Get Search Term Using Observer

Tags: magento2.3, search-terms

I want to get the search term of current user. And according to that search term get products using custom query.

My observer is calling only one time when Cache is enabled.

Please provide me some help or suggestion.

```
<event name="controller_action_postdispatch_catalogsearch_result_index">

    <observer name="searchObserver" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Search\Data" />

</event>


<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Search;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;

class Data implements ObserverInterface {

const COOKIE_NAME = 'categoryId';
const COOKIE_DURATION = 86400; // One day (86400 seconds)

protected $_cookieManager;

/**
 * @var CookieMetadataFactory
 */
protected $_cookieMetadataFactory;
protected $_queryFactory;
protected $_filterBuilder;
protected $_searchCriteriaBuilder;
protected $_searchInterface;

public function __construct(
CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager, CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory, \Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory $queryFactory, \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder, \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder, \Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface $searchInterface
) {
    $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
    $this->_cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
    $this->_queryFactory = $queryFactory;
    $this->_filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->_searchInterface = $searchInterface;
}

/**

 * Below is the method that will fire whenever the event runs!

 *

 * @param Observer $observer

 */
public function execute(Observer $observer) {
    $data = $observer->getData();
    $searchTerm = $this->_queryFactory->get()->getQueryText();
    $this->_filterBuilder->setField('search_term')
        ->setValue($searchTerm)
        ->setConditionType("like");

    $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->_filterBuilder->create());
    $searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
    $searchCriteria->setRequestName("quick_search_container");
    $searchResults = $this->_searchInterface->search($searchCriteria);

    print_r($searchResults->getItems());
    $products = $searchResults->getItems();
    foreach ($products as $product) {

        echo $id = $product->getId();
        $result[] = $id;

    }
    exit;
    return $this;
}

}
```

Comment: Magento does not save customer details with the search term,So you cannot get the current customer search term from default  Magento.
You have to build an extension of your self.

Comment: Please check my question I have updated. Observer is calling only one time when Cache is enabled.